# I'd like to have a UITabBarController, with no UITabBar

Tags: ios, ipad, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I'm building something akin to a UISplitView on the iPad. But the "master" panel would have buttons, instead of a list.

The detail panel would have at most 7 different screens (corresponding to the buttons in the master pane).

So, what I'd like to do is build a UITabBarController in InterfaceBuilder (for no other reason than it's easy to view). But then each button press in the "master" view would tell the tab-bar controller to show a different panel.

Can this be done, or is this approach just silly? I suppose I could create a container view, and swap view-controllers in and out. But using a UITabBarController in IB makes it obvious (visually) that these views are all connected.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the same thing, but I was unable to hide the tab bar in a clean and legal way.

So, I decided to change approach: use the UITabBar in Storyboard only as a "placeholder" for the connections and to fill the `viewControllers` array of my SplitController, then when loading my SplitController, load programmatically the UITabBarController from Storyboard, copy the content of the `viewControllers` array and, finally, dismiss the UITabBarController.

With this approach you have only to manage the transition between a VC and another, but you will have:

- the possibility to set the `viewControllers` from the storyboard (that is the best part imho)
- the possibility to use the `tabBarItem` as an icon for your menu controller

So, to be more schematic:

- Create your SplitController instance with a `NSArray* viewControllers` instance variable
- you can add an `initWithTabBarController:` instance method to your SplitController and pass the programmatically loaded `tabBarController` instance.
- in the `initWithTabBarController` method, fill the `viewControllers` array using the `tabBarController.viewControllers` property. Now you can "trash" your tab bar controller instance, you don't need it
- you have to manage the transition from one controller to another yourself. To do this, I suggest you to use a main view with a container view controller.

I think that this approach is good to have a clean and readable storyboard, I'm updating all my projects to use it.

Regards
Fabio